# Qt: Different tableWidget member names on workstations

Tags: qt, member, qtablewidget

I am using Qt on two ubuntu machines and am copying the source code from time to time between them. I found a really annoying problem when doing that and I can't figure out why this happens.
I am using a table Widget to display some data and want to stretch the horizontal header to fit the content length. To do that I use the following line:

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

This works just fine.
I have a few of this codelines.
However, when I now copy over my source code to the other PC to work on it, I get the following compile error:

> 'class QHeaderView' has no member named 'setResizeMode'

Renaming **'setResizeMode'** to **'setSectionResizeMode'** will work just fine to fix that problem, but if I now copy the source code back to the first PC, it tells me:

> 'class QHeaderView' has no member named 'setSectionResizeMode'

...and I have to rename it to **'setResizeMode'** again, to continue working.
I checked the Qt version on both PCs and they are both **"Qt Creator 2.7.0"** based on **"Qt 5.0.1 (32 bit)"**.
Also the systems are up to date.
The only difference is, that I am using one of them in english system language, the other one in german...but I don't see how that would affect Qt's member declaration. o.O

Anyone knows what the problem is?
The constant renaming can get annoying over time.

Comment: can you check the qglobal headers on each computer (or just the values of `QT_VERSION_STR`) chances are there is a discrepancy there

Comment: Version 4.8.4 on one machine, however I can't check the other one right now. Will report back in about an hour.

Comment: Checked the other PC. Version 5.0.1. So, that's kind of weird. I installed both Qts out of the APT-repository and they are both telling me, that they are up to date. I should maybe reinstall Qt on the other machine from scratch. Thanks for your help. You can post that as answer, if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be that the QT header versions don't match up

double check the `QT_VERSION_STR` in `QtCore/qglobal.h`

for a quick check if you are too lazy add a `#pragma message("QT version: " QT_VERSION_STR)` to the code to have the compiler output it while compiling