# what's wrong with setSectionResizeMode in qt?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qt5.5, qt5.1, qheaderview

I have used qt 5.1.1 for 2 years on Ubuntu. now I install qt 5.5 on it. (I mean both versions are exist on my Ubuntu)
actually this version of Qt framework doesn't work as good as the older one.
so I want to use qt 5.1.1 .

The problem is here that now I have the below error on my code:

code:

```
_headerView->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

error:

```
... error: 'class QHeaderView' has no member named 'setSectionResizeMode'
```

I found [this answer on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592228/qt-different-tablewidget-member-names-on-workstations). but actually I don't get how to solve the problem! It just say its reason.

PS: I want this line of code to stretch my table fix to my window.

Comment: try using `setResizeMode`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Error can happen when you have two or more version of qt installed on your machine.
`setResizeMode` is a old function that override in new versions and changed it's name to `setSectionResizeMode` the safest way to solve this problem is to use `setSectionResizeMode` that you can be sure it will be available by any Qt from 5 and later.

Comment: I do not understand how this can be the accepted solution.  The whole point is that `setResizeMode()` was replaced by `setSectionResizeMode()` and deprecated at Qt 5.0 --- see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview-obsolete.html.  At least by now (Qt 5.7.1) `setResizeMode()` does not exist, so saying "the safest way to solve this problem is to use setResizeMode that you can be sure it will be available by any Qt from 5 and later" is quite wrong, as you most certainly cannot be sure that a deprecated function will still be available in Qt 5 or later.

Comment: @JonBrave you're right, I fixed the answer above. (I assume this was basically a typo.)